# Getting NullPointerException while trying to run jetty start.run

Tags: java, windows, jetty

I am trying to make jetty server as service, and im using this guide:
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-windows-service.html
However I cant make it work, when trying to proceed with:

`java -jar ..\jetty\start.jar --add-to-start=deploy,http,console-capture`

im getting this:

````
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.findMavenLocalRepoDir(StartArgs.java:845)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseBuilder.<init>(BaseBuilder.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)```
````

Comment: That sounds like a weird bug.  Consider filing it at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using version **jetty-distribution-9.4.10.v20180503**. So, I downgrade to **jetty-distribution-9.4.19.v20190610** and it started to work fine. Environment details below:

- Windows 10 Pro
- java version "1.8.0_151"